# How to access a website hosted from a folder located in WordPress directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, subdirectory

I have a WordPress website hosted on amazon ec2 server in /var/www/html/ directory. I also want to host another website that can be accessed using [www.domain.com/admin](http://www.domain.com/admin). I created a folder "admin" inside the WordPress directory but whenever I try t access this new website it shows me the main WordPress website only. I have almost tried everything with .htaccess file but no luck.

currently, my root .htaaccess file looks like this.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|admin/.*)$
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: After a single or several "RewriteCond" lines should be at least a "RewriteRule".  Your last two rules do nothing at all.  Also, this rule "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d" should you allow to access to your admin folder (in fact any folder) instead to load the index.php. Have you created that admin folder in the /var/www/html/admin?

Comment: have you .htaccess file in admin folder  too ?

Comment: @behzadmsalehi Yes, I have a htaccess file inside the admin folder too. It was working fine when it was hosted from hostinger in same way

Comment: @masterguru Yes, I have an admin folder with all the files inside /var/www/html/admin

Comment: @AmitVerma, No there are no other rules

Comment: are you sure  Amazon EC2 uses  Apache ?  if you are using httpd instead of Apache the config file location is in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf  not .htaccess

Comment: @behzadmsalehi That is a very strange statement. "httpd" is the name of the apache http server. The configuration of an apache http server is located unter `/etc/httpd` or similar on unixoid systems. A ".htaccess" file is a _distributed configuration file_ you can use inside an apache http server _in addition_ to the central configuration. Yes, there are other http servers (lighttp, nginx, ...), but httpd is an apache http server.

Comment: You should leave the wordpress rewriting rules alone (that is why they are marked as a block). You want to implement your own rewriting rules for that `/admin` folder as exceptions _before_ the wordpress block, so further up in that ".htaccess" style file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your condition for */admin site before any rule. Thus, you can reach your another web site. Try this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|admin/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```